# Cyclostationary time series

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, forecasting

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclostationary_process

What are the methods in modelling and forecasting such time series?

It is mentioned in the link above that there is a deterministic approach to treat such a time series. Can anyone explain what does it mean?